# PHP and DB Design: Store data in multiple tables and merge or replicate data

Tags: php, sql, database-design

I'm building an application where every user will have a bunch of items. When a user signs up about 150 user specific item are added into a table for every user from a template table.

**Logic as follows: (copy)**
User signs up
Copy 150 template items (rows) from template_table to userItems_table
Display items from userItems_table

The user can change his items (name, price, color) as he wishes in the web UI. Also add new ones, delete existing ones etc.

The question is now.. instead of copying the 150 rows to a user items table.. I could instead just use the template table and when a user accesses the items in the UI I'd do two select statements, then in PHP merge the two arrays to get the users specific items.

**Logic as follows: (overlay)**
User signs up
If user changes an items, store the diff into userItems_table
Select template_table and userItems_table in to two arrays, merge the arrays with an algorithm
Display items from the merged array

The application is expected to grow with around 20 user per week. So in a year there will be around 1000 active users. Equaling at least 150.000 rows per year plus a number of user specific changes. They access the items frequently in the App but they are not changed often. Read ratio a lot higher than write ratio.

My objective is to have a sustainable and scalable design for this.. because a lot of other functions in the app depends on accessing a users item list.

What is the best way of doing this? Any creative ideas?

Thanks!

Additional info:

- Database used is MySQL 5.1 with InnoDB
- Template items will not change during the lifespan of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you go with the option of keeping a template table and then only putting records in the user table for the items that user customized... how about instead of merging the template with the items the user changed, instead do a left outer join.

e.g.

```
select nvl(uit.item_id, itt.item_id) item_id, nvl(uit.name, itt.name) name, nvl(uit.price, itt.price) price
from item_template_table itt
left outer join user_item_table uit
  on itt.item_id = uit.item_id
```

`NVL` is an oracle function that returns the first parameter unless it is null, in which case it returns the second.  If you don't use oracle you can still get this same functionality using a `case` statement or using some proprietary function of your database.

That way every record coming back is the user's overridden item if it exists, else the template one (assuming no null values are allowed in the `user_item_table`... if so, then you need to change the query not to do `nvl` on each column but to check if the primary key in the `user_item_table` to see if it is `null`... if not, then take all the values from the `user_item_table`.

Comment: Thanks, using MySQL. The question is not really how to do the technical implementation rather what would be the best theoretical way to go. What are upsides downsides on using different ways? What are PRO/CONS with your suggestion on left outer join?

Comment: Upsides of the overlay is reduced amount of database storage.  Downside is you have to do this join with the template every time.  Another downside (or upside depending on how you look at it) is that if you add items to the template you only have to do it in the template table... downside is that if you only want certain people to have new template items it's messy.  But if you make a copy each time then you'll have to write code to keep the template in sync with the copies.  So I think it depends on your project & desired behavior rather than there being a good way & a bad way.

Comment: I totally agree with @Renderln. There's no ideal way to do it, and figureing the best way for your situation is, ultimately, a judgement call you have to make.

Comment: I think I will write both functions, populate the DB with a lot of dummy rows then run some benchmarks on different queries utilizing the copy and overlay method and measuring execution time, would that be a good way to measure the effiency of the methods?

Answer (score 1):

One version, you make **copies** of the template set, the other way, you set up an “**overlay**”, where everyone shares the template except for what they’ve changed or added.

Some discussion points to consider.

Performance: In the Copy version, users go to one table to get what they need ( = 1 table hit). In the Overlay version, you always have to go to both tables, first to get what the users’s entered, then to get what they haven’t entered (= 2 tables hits, as per @Renderlin’s null-checking algorithm).

Template Modification over time: what happens when, after T time and N usrers, you decide to add some items to the template. In the Copy version, existing users do not get the new items, while in the Overlay version every user immediately picks up that new item. Similarly, if you choose to change (or drop) a template item, if the user has never modified the item, it is immediately modified for them.

I’ve insufficient information to figure what’s effective and what's not--this must be determined based on your business requirements.

Comment: Hi Philip, the items are based on a yearly basis and the template list will not change for the current year, so let's say it's CD albums, for 2009 the template list will be fixed and for 2010 there will be a new template list which is fixed for the year. There is a column in the tables for which year the item belongs to.. and when a new year comes around it currently copies the rows again from the new year. So in the end of year two there will be 450.000 rows with the copy method given a growth of 1000 users per year.